# print photos with native api in multi platform (window, macos, browser)?

Tags: javascript

I have just assigned strange task (with me) from my boss. That is using native print API of multi platform (window, masos, browser) to print photos from my app. Who did this functional can give me some keywords or good document.

Comment: Do not ask others to do your work for you. Describe your problem, and provide context and a sample of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I think the experience from the others help me save unnecessary stuck.